# web.xml required in Spring applications

Tags: java, spring, deployment, web.xml

A Spring web application is just a normal web application using servlet API 3.0.
In servlet API 3.0 web.xml file is optional (most of the time).
I' ve tried not to include web.xml inside my Spring aplication,but somehow it seems to be required even using Servlet 3.0

The only difference between a Spring applications and web apps I've run successfully without writing a web.xml file, is that in Spring filters and servlets are defined inside jars in the lib folder.

Any clues why this happens ?

Comment: "somehow it seems to be required" That's very vague. Does it work without a `web.xml`? If not, do you get an error?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just exclude the web.xml, as you (at least) need to define which version of the Servlet API are you using.

At the minimum, you'd need this in your `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
```

Everything else (servlets, filters, etc.) can be configured with annotations.

Comment: This is totally wrong. You can build spring web apps completely without web.xml

Comment: @PouyanKhodabakhsh, back in the day you couldn't :)

Answer (score 0):

**Fortunately, you can create completely XML free Spring applications nowadays.** 
There are various different options for such configs with or without Spring Boot.

With pure Spring you can use [AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-container-config)

With Spring Boot, you can have [SpringBootServletInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

This is my [Github repository](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples) with bunch of projects based on both approaches.

Version of servlets is defined by Servlet API you have on your classpath. E.g.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You also don't specify servlets, as Spring has own implementation of servlet [DispatcherServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet).

Filters are registered as beans into Spring context.